Non $C^{*}$-embedded subspace of non-normal Hausdorff space.
I'm trying to prove that in a non-normal Hausdorff space $X$ there exists a subspace $S$ with the property that any completely separated sets in $S$ have disjoint closures in $X$, yet $S$ is not $C^*$-embedded in $X$.
So far, I've found a subset $S$ of $X$ with the stated property that is a closed set and not a zero-set in $X$ (i.e. a subset that is not the zeroes of a continuous function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$). I believe this set is not $C^*$-embedded in $X$ but I don't seem to be able to prove it. Any suggestions on how to proceed?
I'm taking the definition of a $C^*$-embedded subset $S$ of $X$ to be a subset $S$ on which every continuous and bounded function $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ has a continuous and bounded extension to all of $X$.
I also believe that Urysohn's extension theorem might be useful, it states that a subset $S$ of $X$ is $C^*$-embedded in $X$ if every pair of completely separated sets in $S$ are completely separated in $X$.
To be thorough, I'm taking two subsets $A$ and $B$ of $S$ to be completely separated in $S$ to mean that there exists a continuous function $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $A$ and $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ in $B$.
Any help would be appreciated.

A set $S$ as you describe it in the second paragraph, can be $C^\star$-embedded. For instance, $X = \omega_1 + 1$ with the order topology, $S = {\omega_1}$ is closed, any two disjoint sets in $S$ trivially have disjoint closures in $X$, it is not $G_\delta$, hence not zero-set. However, it is $C^\star$-embedded.

Hint (for solving your initial question): what do you know about normality and $C^\star$-embedded subsets?
